# Wordpress dropdown list?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

How do I create a dropdown option list in wordpress? Not a menu in the nav bar, but this kind of dropdown http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list 
Eventually, I would like two of these next to each other asking the user for different things, and email me their responses, but please at least answer my first question for now.

Comment: You're probably better off looking into plugins that will allow you to build WYSIWYG contact forms. I believe Fast Secure Contact Form is one of those: http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-contact-form/

Comment: The problem with WYSIWYG forms are that, in my prior experience, they usually only let the user send a written email to the admin. I specifically need his responses to the options sent to me. For example it could say a.dog b.cat c.hippo, and click [submit], and his choice would be sent to me. Thanks for the suggestion though, I will look into it more.

Comment: You can use a plugin like Contact Form 7. You build the form however you like (even just 1 dropdown list and a submit button). Then you can configure how you want to email to display, including the chosen values of the form fields. 

If something like that doesn't fit the bill, you'll need to describe further what "his choice would be sent to me" means for your desired outcome. If you need the form values sent to some third party data system, or something else, you might have to just hand-code it in a template file.